# Converting A String to a Boolean -- Java

Tags: java, string, boolean

I've been searching around stackoverflow, and I've found a few other questions on converting a string to a boolean, but I can't make it work. Perhaps it is just the way I am trying to use it is incorrect.

Anyways, I am trying to convert two different input strings "M" or "I" in to boolean for use in an if statement. What is basically want the functionality to be is this:

```
// the text that is retrieved is assumed to be either"M" or "I"
M=Input.getText
I=Input.getText

If M shows the value "M",
              do stuff here
else if I shows the value "I",
              do stuff here
else if neither above are true,
              throw an exception here
```

I've tried any number of "toBoolean"s and "Boolean.valueof"s, but none of what I try is working.

PS, Sorry for not having actual code to work with, this is my first step, and thus I haven't built anything up around this piece.

Comment: a) Could you provide some more context? It's currently unclear exactly how you plan to achieve this and how you wish to use the result b) Nice username

Comment: you mean something like `if(m.equals("M"))`?

Comment: How is `Boolean.valueOf` supposed to know if `M` is `true` or otherwise? Just check the value of your String and assign the boolean value to a variable. Better yet, make that a method.

Comment: `if ("M".equals(M)) { ... } else if ("I".equals(I) { ... } else { ... }`. Alternatively you can use a `switch`

Comment: If you wish for "M" or "I" to be anywhere inside of M and I, use the contains() method - `if(M.contains("M") || I.contains("I"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `String`'s methods to check for whether it contains a given literal value, equals it, or equals ignoring case.

A draft condition would be:

```
if ("myValue".equalsIgnoreCase(myText)) {
    // TODO
}
else if ("myOtherValue".equalsIgnoreCase(myOtherText)) {
    // TODO
}
else {
    // TODO
}
```

Here is the documentation in `java.lang.String`:

- [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [equalsIgnorecase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)
- [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

You also want to check the many other methods, such as `startsWith`, `endswith`, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for one boolean:

```
boolean b = (M.equals("M") || I.equals("I"));
```

Or this for two boolean:

```
boolean booleanM = (M.equals("M"));
boolean booleanI = (I.equals("I"));

if(booleanM){
//do stuff here
}else if(booleanI){
//do stuff here
}else{
//do stuff here where both are false
}
```

This is the faster way if you need to verify more than one time, only one time use this:

```
if(M.equals("M")){
//do stuff here
}else if(I.equals("I")){
//do stuff here
}else{
//do stuff here where both are false
}
```

Comment: It's clear from the question that M and I invoke different operations - and a third set of operations if neither are true. This doesn't cover all three scenarios.

Comment: Why assign them to variables at all? It's unnecessary if they're only ever going to be evaluated once anyway. You would be better off just putting the check directly into the `if` condition in those situations. As an aside, string literals can never be `null`, so you should always have them on the left: `"M".equals(M)`.

Comment: Sorry bro, I understand you perfectly, but the questions says convert String to boolean, if he need to use these variables in other part of code he don't need to use other if for check it. Am I correct?

Comment: It does - but in this case it's also not necessary. Perhaps include both options in your answer? One where you store as boolean values that can be re-used later, and another where it's evaluated in the `if` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `boolean b = Input.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("YourTrueString")`. This method will detect if the input text is exactly the same as "YourTrueString". If not, it'll return false. This way anything that isn't true becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

From your pseudo code

```
// the text that is retrieved is assumed to be either"M" or "I"
M=Input.getText
I=Input.getText

If M shows the value "M",
              do stuff here
else if I shows the value "I",
              do stuff here
else if neither above are true,
              throw an exception here
```

To Java

```
// In its own method for reuse, in case you want to extend character support
public boolean match(String character, String match) {
   return character.equals(match);
}
```

You can then invoke this simple method

```
String m = Input.getText();
String i = Input.getText();

if (match(m, "M")) {
   do stuff here
} else if (match(i, "I")) {
   do stuff here
} else {
   throw an exception here
}
```